# Unable to select only first occurrence of multiple attributes with same name?

Tags: html, xpath

Here is my html code:

```
<table id="laptop_detail" class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:18px" class="ha">Camera Pixels</td>
            <td class="val">8 megapixel camera</td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:36px" class="ha">Camera Pixels</td>
            <td class="val">8 megapixel camera</td>
        </tr>  
</tbody>
```

and my xpath:

```
$x('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(., "Camera Pixels")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')
```

My problem is I am unable to find any working way of selecting only one occurrence of attribute.

Comment: "selecting only one occurrence of attribute" as in you just want 1 `<td>` node returned?

Comment: yes and the given answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the part locating the "Camera Pixels" `td` element into parenthesis:

```
(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(., "Camera Pixels")])[1]/following-sibling::td
```

Demo:

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(., "Camera Pixels")])[1]/following-sibling::td'
<td class="val">8 megapixel camera</td>
```